# Essentials hub not working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

On my Bukkit server I installed Hub-Essentials
The problem is when  ever I join it doesn't teleport me from my logout place/world to the place I /hub set.
It also won't give my the items and the book to ex: toggle players.

Can someone tell me:
How to make it teleport me to the place I set the hub.
Why it won't give me the items/book?

I looked in the configs for all them, they are all enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type /reload or just restart the server. If that doesn't work try re-installing it.